# What's the difference between "function x.y()" and "x.y = function ()"?

Tags: javascript

The only difference between these two pieces of code are in line 1 in both blockquotes.

Why do these two pieces of code behave different?

```
function cat.meow() {
    console.log("Meow");
};
```

versus

```
cat.meow = function () {
    console.log("Meow");
};
```

Comment: looks like `int i; i = 100` vs `int i = 100;`, ... no?

Answer (score 6):

The first one is invalid JavaScript, the second is a better idea, more details in the following...

### Why?

Variable / Function names can only have **Letters, Underscores, $, Numbers (if they're not the first character) along with a few other ACII, and unicode characters** (check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names) or [**here**](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) as recommended by [*Kaiido*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) and [*Felix King*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)). It would be the same as `var cat.meow;` which is invalid JavaScript and will throw an error. More specifically

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'.

The compiler is expecting a parenthesis or a space but it sees a period not assuming it is an object. This also happens with bracket syntax for an object :( which means you can't define a function for an object 'item' the first way

### Explanation

When you do:
`foo = function () {}` it *set* the value of *foo* to the function. When you do it as a function `function foo () {}` it 'creates' *foo*.

### So...

The second one is referring to `meow` in `cat`. So it is setting `meow` in `cat` to the function which is valid. That is equivalent to this:

```
var cat = {
    meow: function () {
        console.log("Meow!");
    }
};
```

Obviously is cat isn't defined, this will still throw an error. If you really *really* want to have your function to be called cat.meow *(I would strongly advise against it)*, you would do the following

```
window['cat.meow'] = function () {
    console.log("Meow");
};
```

This clutters the global scope unless you have a different object and is *extremely* bad practice; so if you do use it, do it in secret otherwise almost every programmer will be bashing you on your coding practices.

Comment: *"along with a few other ACII characters"* Actually, unicode letters are allowed as well as you can see in the question you linked to).

Answer (score 3):

Have you at least tried it? The first one isn't a valid javascript. It should produce

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

The second one is valid. In that context, `cat` is an object and you're creating a `meow` method for it.

The error suggests what that `.` is not a valid *identifier*. In javascript, and *most* languages, anything which matches the regex `\w+`, meaning alphanumerical characters + underscore, is a valid identifier.

And in *most* languages, including javascript, it is also mandatory to have the *identifier* begin with an alphabet or underscore. In javascript however, `$` is also a valid identifier.